# Merging two dataframes with same column name but still unique depending on other columns

Tags: python, csv, group-by, merge

I want to merge two dataframes but I can't really seem to get it right. I tried .merge() function with the 'how', 'on' parameters but the output is not the expected result. I'm not a coder and am working on a project. I cant seem to get it right since as you see in the merged_df dataframe, some values are repeated. I'm guessing it has something to do with the groupby() function I used earlier....

This is the 'average_values' dataframe:
[average_values dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJMXZ.png)
[image]

This is the Valscount dataframe
[Valscount dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21S6F.png)
[image]

This is my code so far with the not expected output:
[merged_df dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHV63.png)
[image]

Tried different combinations of paremeters on merge() function

Comment: Welcome to SO. Picture are very poor medium to exchange textual data (code, numbers). Never screenshot, copy paste and format instead. In the present case in addition of being counter productive, it prevents people to help you as if they want to, they will have to input by hand the data.